# Pasar datos del backend a JS

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

estoy retomando un viejo proyecto y tengo un problema simple, quiero pesarle una id a un script de JS para poder hacer una petición con AJAX pero no se como pesarle el id a JS. estoy usando Flask para en backend y con `render_template`paso el objeto zona_actual que contiene el id y mas datos al HTML (el código es de ejemplo):

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', zona_actual = zona_actual)
```

La cosa es que si en el html archivo html abro una etiqueta `<script>` y escribo el código dentro de la etiqueta puedo pesarle el variable de esta forma

```
<script>
    console.log( {{ zona_actual.id }} );
</script>
```

Pero si hago lo mismo pero usando un archivo .JS aparte no funciona por como funciona la función `render_template`, Entonces omo puedo pesarle datos al JS sin tener que escribir el código en el archivo HTML?

Answer (score 1):

El fichero .js es un fichero estático, eso quiere decir que no es modificado por el backend, suponiendo que el id es igual a 1 lo que ocurre cuando en tu fichero html pones

```
<script>
    console.log( {{ zona_actual.id }} );
</script>
```

lo que el servidor devuelve es

```
<script>
    console.log( 1 );
</script>
```

Puedes poner en tu fichero html el siguiente código

```
<script>
    var settings = { 
      zona_actual: 
        id: {{ zona_actual.id }}
      }
    };
</script>
```

y en tu fichero js usar

```
<script>
   console.log( settings.zona_actual.id );
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta soluciona mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un input hidden asi

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ zona_actual.id }}" id="id_zona"/>
```

Y en tu archivo.js declaras una variable obteniendo el valor mediante el id del input

```
var id_zona = $('#id_zona').val()
```

y ya la usas como quieras.